# Phone calls permissions from nowhere?

Tags: java, android

So, Google Play reports that my app uses Phone calls permission. So, I had some permissions, mainly for network and internet and I've deleted all of them and I STILL HAVE phone calls permission!! Here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1.1.2">


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
        <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.MENU" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

                <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.Izbor"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.IZBOR" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

                <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.Pravila"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.PRAVILA" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

                                <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.DvadesetPitanja"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.DVADESETPITANJA" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

                                <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.NeogranicenoPetGresaka"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.NEOGRANICENOPETGRESAKA" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

                                <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.NeogranicenoTriGreske"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.NEOGRANICENOTRIGRESKE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

                                <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.NeogranicenoJednaGreska"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.NEOGRANICENOJEDNAGRESKA" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

                                <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.Kviz"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.KVIZ" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

            <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.Prefs"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.PREFS" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
                     />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> 

            <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.PogresanOdgovor"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.POGRESANODGOVOR" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

            <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.SwarmPopup"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.SWARMPOPUP" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

            <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.NetPopup"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.NETPOPUP" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

            <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.Rezultat"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.REZULTAT" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

            <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.RezultatVreme"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.REZULTATVREME" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

      <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.TacanOdgovor"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.TACANODGOVOR" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

</application>


</manifest>
```

So, apsolutely no permissions in my manifest file, and I still get the Phone calls permission. I DON'T GET IT!

Comment: Try cleaning your project and if it does not working restarting your environment. It usually solves the problem

Answer (score 2):

The compiler automatically adds this permission for compatibility reasons if your app use a library designed to run on Android 1.5 or below (because this permission was introduced in Android 1.6).

I guess it's caused by the AdMob library, which still supports Android 1.5.

Comment: Is there any way to solve this, cause everybody is asking me "OMG phone calls permission!!!WHYYYY"?

Comment: And, I have one app that have no admob ads, and still have Phone Calls permission, so I don't think AdMob is the problem.

Comment: I guess AdMob IS the problem. I don't know how to solve it dough.

Comment: I don't know, but there are lots of apps which require this permission. Look at Angry Birds, it requires the same permission (probably because they use AdMob too).

Comment: I know, but I don't know how to explain this to everyone.